# How to solve this Exception : Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo {...} Didn't find class "..." on path: DexPathList

Tags: android

I'm trying to build use default Empty Activity file at Android Studio. (API 31)

I already search around the web, but I can't find solution for my error.

Here is error message.

2022-05-10 16:14:56.487 1708-1708/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 1708
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~0tsfswauDN0JYmuM-yPM2g==/com.example.myapplication-1g-VIz36fStDuuRgvoCkAA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~0tsfswauDN0JYmuM-yPM2g==/com.example.myapplication-1g-VIz36fStDuuRgvoCkAA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3545)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~0tsfswauDN0JYmuM-yPM2g==/com.example.myapplication-1g-VIz36fStDuuRgvoCkAA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~0tsfswauDN0JYmuM-yPM2g==/com.example.myapplication-1g-VIz36fStDuuRgvoCkAA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1273)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3532)

Here is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Here is build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 31
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Any one have some hint?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing to apply a plugin in your module gradle file.

Try to add this: `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in AndroidManifest.xml, check **packageName** value in the manifest and check if the activities path is correctly opening the desired activity. and you need to check and add all your activity classes there.